# Mutually link Dropdown and text-input values

Tags: jquery, niceforms

Looking  for something that if my select with an id of ***contentPageID*** gets changed then it clears the value of the input with an id of ***itemURL*** and vice-versa. If a value is put for the input text then the val of the select turns to 0.

Comment: I don't know if this is niceforms related but it when I use either of those it doesn't work. I don't know why but I think its niceforms is preventing it from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one more way:

```
$('#contentPageID, #itemURL').change ( function () {

    if ( $(this).is ('select') ) {
        $('#itemURL').val ("");
    }
    else {
        //--- Note that jQuery intelligently sets <select>s.
        $('#contentPageID').val (0);
    }
} );
```

[**See it in action.**](http://jsfiddle.net/K4gnY/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#contentPageID').change(function(){

    $('#itemURL').val("");
});

$('#itemURL').keyup(function(){

    $('#contentPageID').val(0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/bT38s/